# Как подтвердить домен Let's Encrypt по DNS?

Tags: ssl, ispmanager, letsencrypt

При подключении сертификата через ISP Manager выбрал подтверждения через DNS. Панель выдала такое сообщение:

Для продолжения процедуры получения сертификата Let's Encypt sub.domain.ru_sert1 добавьте TXT-записи:

'_acme-challenge.sub.domain.ru. TXT T4Fk9N0KCLiJelOcXjE_ycCLK8SwVaqAFHYoCt0sEn8, 
_acme-challenge.www.sub.domain.ru. TXT SPeLDqoQzM6ffO3LzKiTlvLS6OoO7yRsBWXWDMhzKtM'

на серверах имен 'dns1.hoster.net., dns2.hoster.net., dns3.hoster.net.'.
Получение будет возобновлено после 2018-06-10 16:34:04

Пунктуация сообщения сохранена.

**Вопрос:**
Вот так выглядит интерфейс для создания новой DNS-записи.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тип - txt понятно.

В Имя что писать? `_acme-challenge.sub.domain.ru.` или `T4Fk9N0KCLiJelOcXjE_ycCLK8SwVaqAFHYoCt0sEn8`

В адрес писать `dns1.hoster.net.` или что-то из того что выше? Если да, то одного будет достаточно, или надо все 3?

Comment: Очевидно же: `hostname mode value`.

Comment: @Other hostname это `_acme-challenge.sub.domain.ru.`? mode txt а value это `T4Fk9N0KCLiJelOcXjE_ycCLK8SwVaqAFHYoCt0sEn8`?

Comment: Капитан Очевидность подтверждает.

Comment: нда уж... это же надо такую буйную фантазию иметь, и такое жгучее желание быть неправильно понятым, чтобы вместо «значение» написать «адрес». никому не рекомендовал бы пользоваться программой (или это сайт какой-то?) с подобным интерфейсом.

Answer (score 1):

В качестве имени записи следует указать адрес домена, в вашем случае это

> _acme-challenge.sub.domain.ru.

где domain.ru - фактический адрес вашего домена.

Подробности [здесь](https://letsencrypt.org/ru/docs/challenge-types/)